# How to validate phonenumber in Docusign Phone authentication

Tags: java, docusignapi

I have implemented Docusign Remote Signing Process and added phone authentication by setting identity verification for signer

```
signer.setIdentityVerification(recipientIdentityVerification());


public RecipientIdentityVerification recipientIdentityVerification() throws IOException, ApiException 
{
        RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber phoneNumber = new RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber();
        phoneNumber.setCountryCode("+1");
        phoneNumber.setNumber("**********");

        RecipientIdentityInputOption inputOption = new RecipientIdentityInputOption();
        inputOption.setName("phone_number_list");
        inputOption.setValueType("PhoneNumberList");
        inputOption.setPhoneNumberList(Arrays.asList(phoneNumber));

        RecipientIdentityVerification identityVerifcation = new RecipientIdentityVerification();


        identityVerifcation.setWorkflowId(getWorkflowID());
        identityVerifcation.setInputOptions(Arrays.asList(inputOption));
        return identityVerifcation;

    }
```

Now if we give 10 digit random number, it throws an error code PHONE_NUMBER_INVALID with message Phonenumber is not valid. It only accepts genuine number for which we can get OTP. How to achieve this validation in my app. How can I validate phone numbers entered by our clients?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DocuSign validates the phone number. Not just the format, but also to ensure, for example, that the area code is valid and the phone number is valid (like a number doesn't start with 0 or 1 for example).

To validate the numbers yourself:

- On client - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input
- On server - https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

The server validation above is more thorough and checks more things.